# Binding with DependencyProperty

Tags: silverlight, binding, windows-8, microsoft-metro, dependency-properties

I've defined a class name TextColumns.cs, which has a DependencyProperty RichTextBlockContentProperty:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty RichTextBlockContentProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("RichTextBlockContent", typeof(string),
typeof(RichTextColumns), new PropertyMetadata(""));

public string RichTextBlockContent
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(RichTextBlockContentProperty); }
    set  //Debug, but the SetValue won't fire
    {
        SetValue(RichTextBlockContentProperty, value);
    }
}
```

In the XAML, I use it as

```
<FlipView x:Name="flipView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}">
            <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate  x:Name="myDataTemplate">
                    <UserControl Loaded="StartLayoutUpdates" Unloaded="StopLayoutUpdates">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" Style="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollViewerStyle}" Grid.Row="1">
                            <!-- Content is allowed to flow across as many columns as needed -->
                            <common:RichTextColumns x:Name="richTextColumns" Margin="117,0,117,47"
                                                    RichTextBlockContent="{Binding title}">

                                <RichTextBlock x:Name="richTextBlock" Width="560" Style="{StaticResource ItemRichTextStyle}">
                                    <Paragraph>
                                        <Run x:Name="RunText" FontSize="26" FontWeight="SemiBold" Text="{Binding title}"/>
                                    </Paragraph>
                                </RichTextBlock>
                </common:RichTextColumns>
            </UserControl>
        </DataTemplate> 
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

When the page loaded, it's supposed that the RichTextBlockContent will get the value of the Binding "title", while the Binding in the RichTextBlock worked.

Is there something I've missed?

Comment: You don't close `ScrollViewer` with `</ScrollViewer>`?

Answer (score 1):

The setter won't get called. If you need to do logic when the value gets set you need to supply a PropertyChanged callback in the PropertyMetadata Constructor

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557330.aspx